# allMatches not matching several groups exactly

Tags: regex, dart, capturing-group, named-captures

I thought I knew about regex... Here's the situation:

```
N-U0 U0-M1
M1-T9 T9-R10 R10-E19
E19-L100 L100-B
```

I have a `String` that contains groups (let's call them `transitions`) separated by whitespace (may or may not be line breaks, I'm treating both equally; also, may be one or more characters). Each group is composed of two groups (let's call them `exiting` and `entering`) separated by a hyphen. Each of these is composed of either a single character (`N` or `B`, respectively) or a specific character and a one-or-many-digits number.

I want to run a regex match that will give me one object for each `transition` and then, for each object, I want access to each part of the `transition` by means of named capture groups.

These are the regexes I've written:

```dart
static RegExp regex = RegExp(
  r'(?<exitingN>N)|((?<exitingF>[UMTREL]{1})(?<exitingNumber>[0-9]+))-(?<enteringB>B)|((?<enteringF>[UMTREL]{1})(?<enteringNumber>[0-9]+))\s+',
);

static RegExp exitingRegex = RegExp(
  r'(?<exitingN>N)|((?<exitingF>[UMTREL]{1})(?<exitingNumber>[0-9]+))-',
);

static RegExp enteringRegex = RegExp(
  r'-(?<enteringB>B)|((?<enteringF>[UMTREL]{1})(?<enteringNumber>[0-9]+))',
);
```

When I run

```dart
final matchList = regex.allMatches(
  "N-U0 U0-M1\nM1-T9 T9-R10 R10-E19\nE19-L100 L100-B\n",
);
```

It doesn't work as I expect it to. It matches the first `N`, then the first `U0`, then the first `M1`, and so on until the first `L100` and the `B`. I was expecting it to match `N-U0`, then `U0-M1` and so on. At least `matchList.elementAt(0).namedGroup("exitingN")` etc works, but I wanted the `exiting` and the `entering` parts together.

I tried to add the regex inside another group and I tried both with and without `?:` (to make it non-capturing), plus a few other tests, I think, but nothing worked.

Then I tested with `exitingRegex` only and it worked as expected, matching every `exiting`. However, `enteringRegex` didn't work. It matched every `exiting` and every `entering` except for `N`.

The only way I managed to make it work was to match with `exitingRegex` and then, for the `entering`, I had to first use `"N-U0 U0-M1\nM1-T9 T9-R10 R10-E19\nE19-L100 L100-B\n".replaceAll(exitingRegex, "",)` and then match with `enteringRegex` but without the leading hyphen. This way, I got the `exiting` and the `entering` separately, which I have to join later by index.

What's going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @InSync Strange. This is what was matched with your change: `-U0`, `-M1`, `-T9`, `-R10`, `-E19`, `-L100` and `L100-B`. At least it got the amount right...

Comment: @InSync Of course, I have to apply that change to both sides... It's working now, thanks! Add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Converted to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the branches separated by `|`, wrap them in a group. This group can be a capturing (`()`) or non-capturing group (`(?:)`), depends on what you need. That said, your regex should look like this:

```
(?:
  (?<exitingN>N)
|
  ((?<exitingF>[UMTREL])(?<exitingNumber>[0-9]+))
)
-
(?:
  (?<enteringB>B)
|
  ((?<enteringF>[UMTREL])(?<enteringNumber>[0-9]+))
)
```

For an input of `U0-M1`, this regex matches and returns the following groups:

- 0: `U0-M1`
- 2: `U0`
- `exitingF`: `U`
- `exitingNumber`: `0`
- ...and so on.

Do note that I removed those unnecessary `{1}` because an expression always match 1 instance of itself by default.

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bxe33H/2).